# Unable to display date from SQL Date field without the time automatically added

Tags: c#

C#; .Net 3.5

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", reader2["SentDate"].ToString()));

returns:

7-12-2012 12:00:00 AM

SentDate is a SQL Date field (not datetime), and it only contains "2012-07-12" in the field.

What am I doing wrong?  I only want to have the MessageBox display "7-12-2012" without the "12:00:00 AM".

Comment: `reader2["SentDate"].ToString()` converts the `Date` to a String. Instead of using `String.Format`, why not using `ToString("MMddYY")`

Comment: @Tim:  How do I only display the Date from a string?

Comment: You want to display a string, but you either need to call `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` on the date instance or `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", reader2["SentDate"])`. You should not apply  date formats on a string but on a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take off the `.ToString()`.  You're converting it to a string using the default format before sending it to the template.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", reader2["SentDate"]));
```

Comment: @fraXis This will not format the date in the user's locale (i.e. dd/MM/yyyy for some EU countries). If you want the user to see the date in the form they expect, use `MessageBox.Show(reader2["SentDate"].ToShortDateString());

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = getSomeDateTime();
dt.ToString("MMddyy");
```

you can apply it to your message box by doing

```
MessageBox.Show(reader2["SentDate"].ToString("MMddyy"));
```

[This documentation might help you expand on this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Is there anyway I can display it directly from the reader2?  I don't want to make a new variable to hold the whole value.  I want to read it directly from the database without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @fraXis I've edited my question to demonstrate how to do it without making a new variable

Answer (score 0):

try any of these, if it works

```
        // create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);


    String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year

    String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month

    String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day

    String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}", dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24

    String.Format("{0:m mm}", dt);  // "5 05"            minute

    String.Format("{0:s ss}", dt);  // "7 07"            second

    String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction

    String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes

    String.Format("{0:t tt}", dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.

    String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}", dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

another example of the same here
[look](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)